# IBM i (AS400) Calling SQL Stored Procedure from STRSQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, ibm-midrange

I’m newbie to create DB2 for IBM i (AS400) Stored procedure. I'm seeking an answer for what’s wrong with my calling stored procedure from STRSQL. 
Any ‘IN’ parameter stored procedures are callable, but ‘OUT’ parameter stored procedures are not.

```
create procedure egg(out pcount# INT)
language sql
set option dbgview=*source, USRPRF=*USER
begin
   set pcount# = 5;
end
```

I call this,

```
call egg(?)
```

Then this error shows up.

```
SQL0418
Message . . . . :   Use of parameter marker not valid.
```

I want to see the pcount# result, '5', in the line.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Need to specify a (target) variable in the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do will work, but only if you use iNav's Run SQL Scripts query tool..

```
[ Thu Mar 26 08:50:52 EDT 2015 ]  Run Selected

> call egg(?)

Return Code = 0

Output Parameter #1 = 5

Statement ran successfully   (0 ms)
```

Another option if you're on a recent (7.1+) release, is the use of global variables..

```
create or replace variable myout int default(0)  
call egg(myout)  
select myout from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Note that even in the scenario of using a global variable, iNav's Run SQL Scripts is a better choice as it has a tab you can open to create, update, delete global variables directly.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. So I guess my question now is why the Calling 'IN' parameter Procedure works?

Comment: This is a limitation of STRSQL.

Comment: As @BuckCalabro says, this is simply a limitation of STRSQL.  My guess is that it wasn't designed as a "testing" tool; just a quick & dirty query tool.     Supporting IN parms wasn't a big deal;  OUT is another matter.  Even worse, it doesn't show any returned results set from a stored procedure.  You just get a message, SQL0466 - 1 result sets are available from procedure XXXXXX.   Since IBM provides the more advanced Run SQL scripts tool, they don't see any reason to improve STRSQL.

Comment: wow... Okay. Now I really get that you guys are talking about... I just started using AS400 STRSQL to create and test SQL stored procedurs a couple days ago, so I completely believed that it's capable for me to do the same way to using i Navigator tools, but I guess not. Thank both of you for making me understand those.